# Expected credit card id to be set braintree error

Tags: php, updates, credit-card, braintree-sandbox

I am doing the backend code for a form that updates a credit card through Braintree. I am sure all my values are correct in the JSON. However when I use ajax to go to the backend page I get the following error in the response:

> Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with
>   message 'expected credit card id to be set' in
>   /var/www/html/braiden/braintree/lib/Braintree/CreditCardGateway.php:431
>   Stack trace:
>  
>   #0 /var/www/html/braiden/braintree/lib/Braintree/CreditCardGateway.php(152):
>   Braintree\CreditCardGateway->_validateId(NULL)
>   #1 /var/www/html/braiden/braintree/updateCreditCardBackend.php(18): Braintree\CreditCardGateway->find(NULL)
>   #2 {main}   thrown in /var/www/html/braiden/braintree/lib/Braintree/CreditCardGateway.php on
>   line 431

Here is a copy of the code any help here would be great. 
First heres the json I am giving the backend page:      **{Name: "chicken", cardNumber: "4111111111111111", Cvv: "747", Month: "12", Year: "22"}**

Heres the code

```
<?php  require_once 'lib/Braintree.php';
$requestBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
$requestJSON = json_decode($requestBody);
$name = $requestJSON->Name;
$cvv = $requestJSON->Cvv;
$cardNumber = $requestJSON->cardNumber;
$year =  $requestJSON->Year;
$month = $requestJSON->Month;
$token = $requestJSON->Token;

  $gateway = new Braintree_Gateway([
    'environment' => 'sandbox',
    'merchantId' => '********',
    'publicKey' => '********',
    'privateKey' => '********'
  ]);
$creditCard = $gateway->creditCard()->find($token);
$result = $gateway->creditCard()->update($creditCard->token, [
    'cardholderName' => $name,
    'cvv' => $cvv,
    'number' => $cardNumber,
    'expirationMonth' => $month,
    'expirationYear' => $year
]);
?>
```

Comment: are you updating or adding, if updating you should have the stored id\token. but it actually looks like you want to add one.

Comment: No I have the token id. I just realized its not coming through on the json I checked it and double checked it. It should have passed fine. Can you not pass the token through ajax post

Comment: noting in the code says your using it

Comment: Don't I have to use it to update the credit card?

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the name in the json from Token to tok and it worked apparently token is reserved. like this {["tok": "this.token"]}